# Using intersection within Python to find more then 1 word

Tags: python

I am currently using the following to find if a word or words are within a string:

```
stopwords=set(["Good to Soft","Slow","Standard to Slow","Standard","Standard to Fast","Fast","Heavy","Soft to Heavy","Soft","Yeliding to Soft","Yeilding","Good to Yeilding","Good","Good to Firm","Firm","Hard"])
Going = stopwords.intersection(set(testtext[0].split()))
```

My issue is that if the string has `Standard To Slow`, then the intersection only seems to pick up `Standard`, `Slow` - I want `Standard To Slow`.

Is there anyway I can improve this?

To explain more clearly what outcome I need i will use the example below:

I have a list of goings

```
["Good to Soft","Slow","Standard to Slow","Standard","Standard to Fast","Fast","Heavy","Soft to Heavy","Soft","Yeliding to Soft","Yeilding","Good to Yeilding","Good","Good to Firm","Firm","Hard"]
```

I want to find which of these going are within my string so for example:

> 2:20 - H Brown & Son Recycling Maiden Hurdle (Class4) �4,094 Good
>   2m3f207y

This would return "good" as thats the match

> 2:20 - H Brown & Son Recycling Maiden Hurdle (Class4) �4,094 Good to
>   Soft 2m3f207y

This would return "Good to Soft" as thats the match and NOT "Soft"

Comment: How could `testtext[0].split()` contain `"Standard to Slow"`? It is splitted on spaces so `"Standard to Slow"` has been broken to  `["Standard", "to", "Slow"]`

Comment: Do you want "Standard to Slow" to give "Standard", "Slow" and "Standard to "Slow"? or just "Standard to Slow"?

Comment: Hi Ben. What i am looking to do is find the full match. So the going is good then match it to good but if ita good to firm i want to highlight good to firm. I am looking at taking a string and aeeing what the going is in a horse race

Comment: Are your strings always going to be in the same format?  I would recommend using regex instead of splitting your string.   Although, it's hard to give a good recommendation without knowing what exactly those strings mean.

Comment: Always the same format - they explain the ground conditions of a race (in horse racing) so the ground is slow or that ground is Standard to Slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intersection will only find matching elements.  Here are the lists you are comparing:

```
["Good to Soft","Slow","Standard to Slow","Standard","Standard to Fast","Fast","Heavy","Soft to Heavy","Soft","Yeliding to Soft","Yeilding","Good to Yeilding","Good","Good to Firm","Firm","Hard"]

testtext[0].split() == ["Standard", "to", "Slow"]
```

If you only want it to match what is in `testtext[0]`, then you shouldn't use `split()` to create your list:

```
Going = stopwords.intersection({testtext[0]})
```

Comment: I have edited my string as follows:
stopwords=set(["Good","Standard","Soft","Yeliding","To","Fast","Heavy","Yeilding","Firm","Hard"])

But using Going = stopwords.intersection({testtext[0]}) just gives me set()

Comment: You changed `stopwords` so that it no longer includes `"Standard to Slow"`

Comment: If you are trying to make some sort of ranking system with ranges, then I would have suggested a different approach.  Hence my question/comment on your question.

Comment: To help I have explained my question further